# File Transfer Program in C# leaves artifacts on images and unopenable binary files

Tags: c#, sockets, file-upload, tcp

Text files seem to be alright.
Here is the code that is used to send the files:

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
System.IO.BinaryReader reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream);
double done = 0;
double tot = info.Length;
double chunk = 8096;

while (done < tot)
{
    if (chunk > tot - done)
    {
        chunk = tot - done;
    }
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[(int)chunk];
    reader.Read(buffer,(int)done,(int)chunk);
    sock.Send(buffer);
    done += chunk;
    statusTxt.Text = Math.Round(done / tot * 100, 2).ToString() + "%";
}
```

And the code to receive the files is very similar:

```
private void ReceiveFile(string file, Socket sock,double size)
{
    while (done < size)
        {
            if (chunk > (size - done))
            {
                chunk = size - done;
            }
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[(int)chunk];

            int count = sock.Receive(buffer);
            writer.Write(buffer);
            done += count;

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
            {
                foreach (TextBlock block in files.Items)
                {
                    if (block.Tag.ToString() == file)
                    {
                        block.Text = "Uploading " + file + "... 0% ("+done.ToString()+"/" + size.ToString() + ")";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

I have seen many posts concerning image artifacts, but all the problems dealt with bytes being encoded to text. I believe that I've avoided that problem. I use Byte arrays during the entire process and I keep track of how many bytes are being read, but the images still end up corrupted. I checked the files, and they contain the same exact amount of bytes on the client and server, so SOMETHING is going on the server, but its just not correct. Anything wrong with the code, or could it be a server issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mostly ignore the count of bytes actually sent/received. Especially `writer.Write(buffer);` writes the entire buffer, regardless whether it was entirely filled by `sock.Receive(buffer);` before.